# Bug in Safari: options.length = 0; not working as expected in Safari 4

Tags: javascript, safari, google-chrome, webkit

This is not a real question, but rather an answer to save some others the hassle of tracking this nasty bug down. I wasted hours finding this out.

When using `options.length = 0;` to reset all options of a select element in safari, you can get mixed results depending on wether you have the Web Inspector open or not.
If the web inspector is open you use `myElement.options.length = 0;` and after that query the `options.length()`, you might get back 1 instead of 0 (expected) but only if the Web Inspector is open (which is often the case when debugging problem like this).

### Workaround:

Close the Web Inspector or call `myElement.options.length = 0;` twice like so:

```
myElement.options.length = 0;
myElement.options.length = 0;
```

### Testcase:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <title>Testcase</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">
function test(el){
 var el = document.getElementById("sel");
 alert("Before calling options.length=" + el.options.length);
 el.options.length = 0;
 alert("After calling options.length=" + el.options.length);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="test();">
<p>
Make note of the numbers displayed in the Alert Dialog, then open Web inspector, reload this page and compare the numbers.
</p>

<select id="sel" multiple>
 <option label="a----------" value="a"></option>
 <option label="b----------" value="b"></option>
 <option label="c----------" value="c"></option>
</select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd ever want to force the length of an array to zero like that anyway, especially one as semantically entangled as the "options" property of a `<select>` element.

Comment: @Pointy: It's useful for removing a number of `option` elements with a single, clean line of code, and more efficient than `innerHTML` if you're not clearing the select element completely.  I don't really see a problem with using it vs `innerHTML`, anyway.

Comment: Well if it works I guess it's fine. It just seems like "tempting fate" to me, but I tend to be cautious. (Oh, and I guess as this very question indicates, it doesn't necessarily work all the time ...)

Comment: It does work all the time, except if the browser runs into a very weird bug which in this case has nothing to do with its JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: @Jeff: Why did you add google-chrome as a tag?  I'm not clear on the relation.

Comment: @Beska: Because it doesn't work in Chrome too.

Answer (score 3):

Close the Web Inspector or call myElement.options.length = 0; twice like so:

```
myElement.options.length = 0;
myElement.options.length = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce that with current dev-channel version. 5.0.375.6

Comment: I mean in Chrome. Also it is working fine in WebKit which was built from the latest sources.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myElement.options.splice(0, myElement.options.length);
```

(first param is the starting index, second param indicates how many elements to delete)